# Integrate rule from Guvnor into Java

Tags: java, drools, kie, guvnor

1. Project my-app:

   - some POJOs and some business logic classes
   - put only the POJOs from above project inside a jar
2. Import above jar into Guvnor

   - define rules from user interface (UI), not like DRL file
   - mock test pojo data in Guvnor
   - test the rules
   - publish/export the rules for execution in java runtime using drools API
3. import the rules into the my-app and execute it

   - import the rules (WHAT will be the format of the import?)
   - execute the rules inside business logic using drools/KIE API as follows:

     ```
     kSession.insert(pojoInstance);
     kSession.fireAllRules();
     ```

Is this a right approach? If not, can someone guide how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

Approach you mentioned looks good to me. I am not sure which version of drools you are using but if you are using Drools 7/6 then you can think of using kie-server. Kie-server provide REST API for rule execution and it support kie-Scanner API's through which you can update rules at runtime without downtime. It will save efforts of exporting rules/jar and using  them in application.